# Can't get into Debian console interface after login!

Tags: debian, terminal, virtual-machine, login, gui

[image]

Tried to find the solution online but was not able to find any.

How can I enter into graphical user interface?

I even used right password but still it's stuck on this terminal mode.

Comment: You are root, so no need for sudo. It doesn't seem to be installed anyway and that's my guess. Did you even selected Desktop Environment while installation? What happens if you try "startx". I will post an answer as try out. PS You can also try gnome-session or mate-session.

Comment: well i tried that but it did not worked but thanks for help buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment. If that does not work, try:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
reboot
```

After the reboot

```
tasksel install desktop gnome-desktop
```

You will need internet for downloading the packages.
Maybe read the following [page](https://linuxhint.com/install_gnome_debian_10_minimal_server/).

Comment: thanks for help!!! it's now installing packages!!!

Comment: If it works, don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: yeah sure buddy!